# Program to create customized Linux live disk

Tags: debian, live-usb

A year or so ago I created a custom live disk of Mint 19. However, I forgot which program I used to do this. (I don't see anything relevant listed in Software Manager.) The only clue I have is the startup screen. Does anyone recognize the program based on this yellow screenshot? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Maybe [cubic](https://launchpad.net/cubic)?

Comment: Try `BalenaEtcher`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/), which even is multi-platform and can automatically download a distro of choice (large selection though not exhaustive).

HTH, ppenguin

Comment: That tool does not allow me to customize the Live disk with different apps as far as I can tell.

Comment: @posfan12: yes, UNetbootin is only for making a bootable stick from ISO images. And recently for a Manjaro install I got a grub filesystem error, which was solved by using BalenaEtcher. So YMMV apparently.

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. I am looking for a tool to customize the Live disk not write it to a CD or thumb drive.